# iOS - Facebook - You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

upon Facebook login, I am getting this message on the Facebook side: "You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x. v1.0 will be deprecated on April 30, 2015.

I have visited the Facebook page but it is unclear to me what I need to do. It had seemed I need to just update the Framework in Xcode to version 3.20 which I have done, but I still am getting this message.

I have cleaned the App before running but I am still encountering this message. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: r u try in the new app ID, new permissions..,

Comment: Sorry, i do not know what you mean.

Comment: You need to do all API calls using v2.0 or later in the url. Are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry, this is iOS so I am not calling using URLs.

Comment: I am doing basic login using this guide from Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2. I have followed it exactly and updated my SDK. I'm at a loss.

Comment: any fix for this, @mreynol?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I updated the framework through Xcode and nothing. What I found was that the `FacebookSDK.framework` in my application folder was not being updated. I deleted and updated with the new framework that I download from Facebook website. It worked. No more warning. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the docs. Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading#313to314
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBRequest/#overrideVersionPartWith:

Comment: I did read through them and this is what i find: "The Facebook iOS SDK is automatically pinned to the most recent version of the API when the SDK is released. It will automatically add the version number to any API calls you make. Upgrading the version of the SDK you're using will automatically update the version of the underlying API that's used." So, it appears that i should only need to replace the Facebook framework with the new SDK which I have done. I'm not sure what i'm missing. I appreciate the help here.

Comment: Tobi, i'm not sure what i am missing but it appears I am doing things correct. I have updated SDK and can see the header files within the framework reference 3.2 and graph 2.2. It seems my app should be making the calls with correct version but i continue to get the message on FB side.

Comment: I've upgraded and am still getting the message too.

Comment: same here. typical FB: overload of documentation, nothing clearly defined for simple things..reminds me of oracle or amazon documentation style

Comment: They only tell us how to update Android apps. Nothing on iOS there besides updating the SDK framework, which I've done.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delayed response but what camus wrote above was my solution as well. I found i was not linking in plist to the same framework that i had downloaded.