# Facebook iOS SDK: Why am I getting "You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x"?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am in the process of adding Facebook support (login, posting) to our iOS app. I have downloaded and linked against the latest iOS libraries as of a week or two ago (FBSDKCoreKit.framework and FBSDKLoginKit.framework). However, when I attempt to authorize the app, I get the warning "You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x".

I have no idea why it thinks I'm using an older API version. The Facebook app record is pretty old and had been dormant for some time, but the actual client code has been completely rewritten against the latest libraries. Do I perhaps need to update some settings in the Facebook app record?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986922/ios-facebook-you-must-upgrade-this-app-to-graph-api-v2-x

Comment: Saw that, doesn't help. The libraries are definitely up to date.

Comment: You can refer this link to know more about it... https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/12/18/making-it-easier-to-upgrade-to-api-v2.x/

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. It seems my test users are working fine but regular users are getting the warning.

Comment: How are you getting your users logged in and sharing content on facebook?

Comment: You can refer to this link too.. Hope it helps :)   http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/53078-upgrading-your-apps-to-graph-api-v2x-facebook/

Comment: @devios: regular users should not see this warning at all, it is supposed to be displayed to developers as an FYI. If you can confirm that users see this, please file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and posted a similar question ([Facebook iOS SDK 4.0.1 "You must upgrade this app to Graph API v2.x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29610835/facebook-ios-sdk-4-0-1-you-must-upgrade-this-app-to-graph-api-v2-x/29656646#29656646)).

For me the problem was solved when I deleted `/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`